# Converting From JSON to CSV Getting System.Object[] issues in PowerShell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation

I wanted to export DNS Recordsets into blob storage. I am using the following powershell code to get the recordsets of all the DNS Zones converting to JSON and exporting into CSV and then uploading into blob.

```
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey
$zones = Get-AzDnsZone
foreach ($zone in $zones) {
    $recordSets = Get-AzDnsRecordSet -ZoneName $zone.Name -ResourceGroupName $zone.ResourceGroupName
    $json = $recordSets | ConvertTo-Json
    $jsonR = ConvertFrom-Json $json
    $jsonR | Export-Csv "DNS.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
  $result = Set-AzStorageBlobContent -Context $context -Container "venkat" -File "DNS.csv" -Blob "DNS.csv" -Force
}
```

However The Recordsets in blob is not getting displayed as expected. In Records column the values are showing as `"System.Object[]"`

This is how json Output Looks like

```
[
    {
        "Id":  "ID",
        "Name":  "@",
        "ZoneName":  "zonedns.com",
        "ResourceGroupName":  "dnsautomationrg",
        "Ttl":  172800,
        "RecordType":  5,
        "TargetResourceId":  null,
        "Records":  [
                        {
                            "Nsdname":  "ns1-04.azure-dns.com."
                        },
                        {
                            "Nsdname":  "ns2-04.azure-dns.net."
                        },
                        {
                            "Nsdname":  "ns3-04.azure-dns.org."
                        },
                        {
                            "Nsdname":  "ns4-04.azure-dns.info."
                        }
                    ],
        "Metadata":  null,
        "ProvisioningState":  "Succeeded"
    },
    {
        "Id":  "ID2",
        "Name":  "@",
        "ZoneName":  "zonedns.com",
        "ResourceGroupName":  "dnsautomationrg",
        "Ttl":  3600,
        "RecordType":  7,
        "TargetResourceId":  null,
        "Records":  [
                        {
                            "Host":  "ns1-04.azure-dns.com.",
                            "Email":  "azuredns-hostmaster.microsoft.com",
                            "SerialNumber":  1,
                            "RefreshTime":  3600,
                            "RetryTime":  300,
                            "ExpireTime":  2419200,
                            "MinimumTtl":  300
                        }
                    ],
        "Metadata":  null,
        "ProvisioningState":  "Succeeded"
    },
{
    "Id":  "ID3",
    "Name":  "test",
    "ZoneName":  "zonedns.com",
    "ResourceGroupName":  "dnsautomationrg",
    "Ttl":  3600,
    "RecordType":  0,
    "TargetResourceId":  null,
    "Records":  [
                    {
                        "Ipv4Address":  "10.0.0.0"
                    }
                ],
    "Metadata":  null,
    "ProvisioningState":  "Succeeded"
}
]
```

When exporting to blob in CSV this is what I am facing issue with

[image]

Expecting the Output should be like this
[image]
Any suggestions on how to fix this issue.

Comment: Can you show an example of a value of ```$json```? And I’m not sure why you’re calling ```ConvertTo-Json``` just to call ```ConvertFrom-Json``` straight after - it seems like a null-op step unless I’m missing something?

Comment: @mclayton I have updated my question with better details. Hope this brings some clarity of the issue I'm facing

Comment: ok, cool. And can you show what you're expecting the result to look like in your example (manually edit the csv / excel file with your data and show the result)?

Comment: @mclayton when exporting csv to blob, I'm Expecting the whole value in records should be populated in records column without curly braces or even with it is also fine. As i am expecting the same data to be present in records section of CSV

Comment: Ok. Can you show a concrete example of that rather than a description - use your sample data and show us what you want the result to look like…

Comment: @mclayton Updated it for better visibility. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So your issue is that you want the `Records` property to be converted into a formatted string in your csv file, but it's value is a nested *array* of objects and the default behaviour for `Export-Csv` and `ConvertTo-Csv` is to serialize it to the *type name* of the property value - i.e. `System.Object[]`.

You can see that here:

```
@{ "col1" = "aaa"; "col2" = @( "bbb", "ccc" ) } | ConvertTo-Csv

# "col1","col2"
# "aaa","System.Object[]"
```

If you want the `Records` property to be turned into a different string you're going to have to do the serialization yourself.

The first thing to do is get all the recordsets for all the zones into a single array:

```
$recordsets = $zones | Get-AzDnsRecordSet;
```

and then we can convert them into a slightly different structure that will serialize into the output you want:

```
$converted = $recordsets | Select-Object -Property @(
  "Id", "Name", "ZoneName", "ResourceGroupName", "Ttl", "RecordType", "TargetResourceId",
  @{"l"="Records"; "e"={
    @(
      $_.Records | foreach-object {
        $_.psobject.Properties | foreach-object {
          $_.Name + "=" + $_.Value + ";"
        }
      }
    ) -join "`r`n"
  }},
  "Metadata", "ProvisioningState"
);
```

This is basically creating new objects that have the same properties and values, *except* for the `Records` property, which is converted into a multi-line string containing the properties from all records in each RecordSet.

Once you've got that you can convert it to a csv (or export it to a file) like this:

```
$converted | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation
```

The result is this somewhat-garbled mess due to the line breaks in the data:

```
"Id","Name","ZoneName","ResourceGroupName","Ttl","RecordType","TargetResourceId","Records","Metadata","ProvisioningState"
"ID","@","zonedns.com","dnsautomationrg","172800","5",,"Nsdname=ns1-04.azure-dns.com.;
Nsdname=ns2-04.azure-dns.net.;
Nsdname=ns3-04.azure-dns.org.;
Nsdname=ns4-04.azure-dns.info.;",,"Succeeded"
"ID2","@","zonedns.com","dnsautomationrg","3600","7",,"Host=ns1-04.azure-dns.com.;
Email=azuredns-hostmaster.microsoft.com;
SerialNumber=1;
RefreshTime=3600;
RetryTime=300;
ExpireTime=2419200;
MinimumTtl=300;",,"Succeeded"
"ID3","test","zonedns.com","dnsautomationrg","3600","0",,"Ipv4Address=10.0.0.0;",,"Succeeded"
```

but if you open it in Excel you'll see the output you wanted:

[image]